# Is google-services.json file unique for different apps?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services

I am trying to implement Firebase in my app. In the second step, it says to download and add google-services.json. My question is if last month I implemented an old app with Firebase and added that google-services.json to that app, can I add the google-services.json file of that old app in my new app or I should redownload it as it is unique for every different app/Firebase project?

In summary, can I use the same google-services.json for every app I have or I should download the google-serices.json associated with each Firebase project as it is unique for each different app?

Thanks

Comment: you have to create new file for each app because of their unique `package_name`

Comment: According to your comment I can conclude that the google-services.json has a certain package_name inside it, right?

Comment: Yes.  `google-services.json` is generated when you create project in your firebase console. in which you can add apps to your project for some platform and this file get generated for each platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I add the google-services.json file of that old app in my new app or I should redownload it as it is unique for every different app/Firebase project?

No, you should always download the google-services.json file each time a new application is added to your Firebase project. Why? That's because each application is identified through its own unique package name.

Comment: What i can notice is this file contains all the apps made under that project, shouldn't it be different per app, so it should contain just the values for that app.

Comment: @Miguel No, it should contain the details of all applications that exist in the project.