# Firebase Firestore permission denial

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an flutter app that talks to the same collection and everything works fine. However, I have another flutter app app which I have also added to Firebase and done all the configuration as in the first app but I keep getting the error as added below.

[Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(consultations/6437f769a0016e1e8fe563b0/matters order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Also, I have set my rules as follows

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I will really need someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that your Flutter app with the issue is pointing to the same Firestore instance where you have deployed the rules you listed in your question? The PERMISSION_DENIED error typically means that your request is blocked by Firestore rules. But the rules snippet you posted allows read and write access to all documents. It almost sounds like you are connecting to a different Firestore with a different or more restrictive set of rules.

Comment: I have added the google_services.json file generated from the firebase project with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to clean my project and rebuild. This is because, I changed the firebase' google-services.json file from a previous firebase account to the current one.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki for everyone's visibility. As mentioned by most200, the PERMISSION_DENIED error typically means that the request is blocked by Firestore rules. As seen in the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74275497/is-google-services-json-file-unique-for-different-apps) that was recognized by Google Cloud, google-services.json should always be updated each time a new application is added to your Firebase project. That's because each application is identified through its own unique package name. That is why cleaning and rebuilding your project is necessary.